# How to make calculations in Java that start from the start when it gets past a range?

Tags: java

How do I make a calculation in Java so that it starts at the edge of the range once it gets past it?

For example,
if range is 0 to 4,

- 4-7=2,
- 3-7=1,
- 0+5=0,
- 2+2=4 (normal case)

Comment: Where does 4-7=2 and 3-7=1?

Comment: I understand now sorry never mind. Its a wrap around. Sounds like you need a class to hold integer values and implement your own operators. Or a static class that held range variables and add(int, int) and substract etc methods.

Comment: look up the modulo operator (%). in this case it would be (a+b) %5. This may produce negative values so you might need instead ((a+b) %5 +5) %5

Answer (score 0):

- Start by taking the size of the range, which is `S=Hi-Lo+1`. In your case the size would be `S=4-0+1=5`. `Hi` is the high end of the range; `Lo` is its low end.
- Make your computations modulo the size of the range: when computing `A <op> B`, compute `Lo+(((A-Lo)%S) <op> ((B-Lo)%S))`, where `<op>` is your operation `+` or `-`.

The above will give you the results for any positive `A` and `B` and an additive operation `<op>`.

In your case `Lo` is zero, and the left-hand side (i.e. `4`, `3`, `0`, and `2`) is inside the range, so the only adjustment you need to make is to the right-hand side:

- `4-7 = 4-7%5 = 4-2 = 2`
- `3-7 = 3-7%5 = 3-2 = 1`
- `0+5 = 0+5%5 = 0+0 = 0`
- `2+2 = 4` (the normal case).

Comment: @rageagainstthecomputer Did you get a chance to try this out?